Use of the eigenfunction expansion of Green's function in physics and physical significance
In physics, we find extensive use of Green's function in almost all branches of physics. To find the Green's function of an ODE, we usually solve an equation of the form
$$L_xG(x,y)=\delta(x-y)\tag{1}$$ subject to appropriate boundary conditions. Recently I have also learnt the eigenfunction expansion of Green's function:
$$G(x,y)=\sum_j\frac{\phi_j(x)\phi_j^*(y)}{\lambda_j-\lambda},\tag{2}$$
where $\{\phi_j\}$ is a complete set of orthonormal eigenfunctions with eigenvalues $\{\lambda_j\}$ i.e.,
$$L_x\phi_j(x)=\lambda_j\phi_j(x), \qquad\int\phi^*_j(x)\phi_k(x)=\delta_{jk}.\tag{3}$$ But I haven't seen any application of it so far. So I don't feel it in my bones. Does the formula Eq.(2) find any application and physical significance in physics? I'd appreciate it if someone could illustrate this with a simple example.

Please provide a reference for the expression in (2).

In the bra-ket notation of quantum mechanics, we could express this as
$$G(x,y) = \langle x |G|y\rangle$$
$$L_xG(x,y) = \langle x|L G|y\rangle$$
$$\delta(x-y) = \langle x|y\rangle$$
and so
$$LG = \mathbf 1 \iff G = L^{-1}$$
Given that this is the case,
$$G(x,y) = \langle x|G|y\rangle =\langle x | L^{-1}|y\rangle = \sum_j \langle x|L^{-1} |\phi_j\rangle\langle \phi_j| y\rangle$$
$$= \sum_j \frac{\langle x|\phi_j\rangle \langle \phi_j | y\rangle}{\lambda_j} =\sum_J \frac{\phi_j(x) \phi^*_j(y)}{\lambda_j}$$
In other words, the eigenvalue expansion is essentially just the statement that the Green's function corresponding to a (self-adjoint, or at least normal) operator on a Hilbert space is just that operator's inverse. This finds plenty of application in quantum mechanics - particularly in the realm of perturbation theory.

For a taste of the physics behind it, we might consider a string fixed on both ends subject to the wave equation
$$\frac{\partial^2 \sigma}{\partial x^2} - \frac{1}{c^2} \frac{\partial^2 \sigma}{\partial t^2} = f(x)e^{i\omega t} $$
with the RHS some forcing term. Assuming a periodic solution $a(x) e^{i\omega t}$ in the steady state, we find
$$a'' + k^2a = f(x,t) \qquad k^2 = \frac{\omega^2}{c^2}$$
The operator $\frac{d^2}{dx^2} + k^2$ is self-adjoint on the Hilbert space of twice weakly differentiable functions subject to the boundary conditions $a(0) = a(L) = 0$. Its eigenfunctions and eigenvalues take the forms
$$\phi_n(x) = \sqrt{\frac{2}{L}}\sin\left(\frac{n\pi}{L} x\right)$$
$$\lambda_n = k^2 - \left(\frac{n\pi}{L}\right)^2$$
so the Green's function is then
$$G(x,y) = \frac{2}{L}\sum_n \frac{\sin\left(\frac{n\pi}{L} x\right)\sin\left(\frac{n\pi}{L} y\right)}{k^2 - \left(\frac{n\pi}{L}\right)^2}$$
Observe that the resonances of the system correspond to poles of the Green's function - in QFT, this turns into the statement that bound states correspond to poles of the propagator.

Nitpick: The GF you obtained is the GF of the ODE obtained in the steady state. The argument $y$ in $G(x,y)$ is different from the the string displacement $y$ in the PDE you considered. Maybe $G(x,x')$ will be a better notation. Thanks for the answer! :-)

I have a follow-up question. The eigenfunction expansion formula seems to apply only to ODEs. Can it be generalized to PDEs?

@Solidification Edited, thanks. As for your follow-up, yes it generalizes straightforwardly in the sense that $x\mapsto \mathbf x=(x_1, x_2,\ldots)$ and the eigenvalues and eigenfunctions may be labeled by multi-indices.

J. Murray’s answer is complete and helpful, but as a quick heuristic I would say:
Equation (1) is the definition of the Green’s function.
Equation (2) is a convenient way to find the Green’s function if you already know the spectrum of a given operator.
